# How to get the custom values and image in Magento in Topmenu?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, menu, magento-1.7, categories

I'm using **magento 1.7.0.2**. I have add the custom value in database. But how to retrive the custom value and image in Topmanu. I have tried in below mentioned code in the palce of 'my_attribute' to replace my attribute, but i din't get the result.

**Model: Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer**

**Method: _addCategoriesToMenu()**

$categoryData = array(

```
'name' => $category->getName(),
'id' => $nodeId,
//'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
'my_attribute' => $category->getData('my_attribute') // Add our data in...
```

);

When i print the array i'll get this,

Array ( [name] => Matelas [id] => category-node-31 [is_active] => 1 [my_attribute] => )

Can any one guide me, Thanks in advance...

Comment: you mean category image ? and what custom value you mean ?

Comment: I have get the custom category value using below code. But the same place ('my_attribute') , replace image attribute it does not work. I need the image to show in the Topmenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you mean you have added a new custom attribute to the Category entity?

Becuase you are dealing with a Node_collection the full category object won't be loaded, try loading the full object to get what you're after:

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());

$categoryData = array(
    name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    //'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
    'my_attribute' => $cat->getData('my_attribute') // Add our data in...
);
```